# Creating custom Dead Letter Queue

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I am using activemq 5.10,
I want to create a custom Dead letter queue for all my queues.

I know that activemq itself provides inbuilt DLQ by name `ActiveMQ.DLQ` but I want my custom DLQ to hold all the failed messages.

I also know that we can create individual DLQ for each queue,but thats not what I want

any pointers will be helpful,
Thanks.

Comment: message expiry can not be detected by receiver. so no direct way. how about creating forwarding mechanism. MyQ.DLQ -> MyGlobalDLQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple, but not documented as far as I know. Specify the queue in a sharedDeadLetterStrategy. Verified in AMQ 5.9.0 but may as well work in earlier/later versions as well.

```
<deadLetterStrategy>
    <sharedDeadLetterStrategy>
        <deadLetterQueue>
            <queue physicalName="CUSTOMDLQ"/>
        </deadLetterQueue>
    </sharedDeadLetterStrategy>
</deadLetterStrategy>
```

Answer (score 1):

This cant be done in current ActiveMQ version(5.10), so we decided on creating custom exception queues and forwarding messages to them based on particular exception scenarios.